# WebSocket ws how to simulate error event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm using the WebSocket library ws for node.js and I'm trying to simulate an error event on the server that would trigger my error handling code:

```
    ws.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("error occured");
    });
```

I tried referencing an undefined variable in the on('message') event but that just crashed the whole server and the 'error' event never fired.

Can anyone tell me how to simulate a ws error event on the server?

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just emit it manually (e.g. `ws.emit('error', new Error('foo'))`) or pull the `error` event handler out and call it directly?

Comment: ws.emit('error') worked, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Manually emitting the event should work (`ws.emit('error', new Error('foo'))`) as well as calling the `error` event handler directly (by pulling it out and naming it).

Comment: Could you show a example how ou call the `error handler` directly?